# How to store text in AndroidKeyStore?

Tags: android, keystore, secret-key

I'm trying to store a short piece of text inside Android's Secure element using the following code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);

PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(null);

SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEwithHmacSHA1");
SecretKey generatedSecret = factory.generateSecret(newPBEKeySpec(mySecureText.toCharArray()));

ks.setEntry("alias", new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(generatedSecret), keyStorePP);
```

The code above gives the following exception:

```
08-17 14:39:32.832: W/System.err(11713): java.security.KeyStoreException: Unsupported protection parameter class: java.security.KeyStore$PasswordProtection. Supported: android.security.keystore.KeyProtection
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or just AndroidKeyStore does not support storing strings?

Last thing, if I'll switch to BKS the code will execute.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you to change this:

```
PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(null);
```

To this

```
PasswordProtection keyStorePP = new KeyStore.KeyProtection();
```

Comment: According to documentation, the PasswordProtection ctor must receive char[] password (could be nullable). the error comes from: SecretKeyEntry(generatedSecret), keyStorePP);

Answer (score 0):

KeyProtection cant set null password.

```
char[] password = {'p','a','s','s'};
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam =
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);
ks.setEntry("alias", new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(generatedSecret), keyStorePP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work below. This is how you specify new KeyProtection:

```
        import android.security.keystore.KeyProtection;
        import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties;
        ...............

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null, null);      

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(mySecureText.getBytes());
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);
        keyGenerator.init(256, secureRandom);
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyGenerator.generateKey().getEncoded(), KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES);


        keyStore.setEntry(alias, new SecretKeyEntry(keySpec),
                          new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                                             .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                                             .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                                             .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
                                             .build()
        );
```